# FMResultSet parameterized query returns no results xcode

Tags: xcode

I get no result when using the below query however i do when i say "SELECT * FROM ORDER_HEADER".  I have typed "SELECT * FROM ORDER_HEADER WHERE CUSTOMER = 1" in SqlLite Database Browser and gotten back the correct data.  Why am i not receiving my row result?
I have also tried SELECT * FROM ORDER_HEADER WHERE CUSTOMER = %d",1.  Thank you for your help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

[super viewDidLoad];
salesOrders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *databasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MobilePDQ"];
FMDatabase *db  = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:databasePath];
[db open];
FMResultSet *fResult = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ORDER_HEADER WHERE CUSTOMER = %d",1];
NSLog ( @"has results: %@", [fResult hasAnotherRow] ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
while([fResult next])
{
    SalesOrderHeaderController *salesOrder = [SalesOrderHeaderController alloc];
    salesOrder.salesOrderID = [fResult intForColumn:@"ID"];
    salesOrder.creationDate = [fResult stringForColumn:@"CREATION_DATE"];
    [salesOrders addObject:salesOrder];
}
[db close];}
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the CUSTOMER column being a Numeric type?  I tried saying "SELECT * FROM ORDER_HEADER WHERE ID = 1" and it worked where ID is an integer primary key datatype.  That being said.  What do i need to do to search by a Numeric datatype?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing .sqlite in database name. Check if db is opened or not. Also try this query

```
[db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ORDER_HEADER WHERE CUSTOMER = ?",[NSnumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

Your problem might be resolved.

Comment: That is not it as i get a result when i use the statement "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER".  I did figure out that since CUSTOMER is the datatype numeric in sqlite i change it to integer and the results came up.